# Запрос на сравнение больше/меньше

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется запрос вида:

```
SELECT
    measuring.pin_name AS pin_name,
    AVG(measuring.meas) AS meas,
    COUNT(measuring.meas) AS counts
FROM
    measuring,
    list_ims,
    test_name,
    test_variant,
    party_ims
WHERE
    (
        measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
    ) AND(
        measuring.id_party = party_ims.id AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
    ) AND list_ims.name = '1533ИР39' AND test_name.name = 'Выходное напряжение высокого уровня UOH, В'
GROUP BY
    `pin_name`
ORDER BY
    `measuring`.`pin_name` ASC
```

На выходе возвращается список вида

```
pin_name 1 | среднее | количество сущностей с  pin_name 1   
pin_name 2 | среднее | количество сущностей с  pin_name 2
pin_name 3 | среднее | количество сущностей с  pin_name 3
```

В последствии средствами `python` считается количество pin_name, после этого среднее каждой сущности сравнивается с пользовательским числом и проверяется если новое количество pin_name осталось прежним, то всё круто, добавляю головной элемент (тот, у кого были все эти `pin_name` в массив на вывод пользователю), но при этом надо также посчитать количество `pin_name` у которых значение (уже не среднее) больше/меньше пользовательского значения.
Сейчас делаю это через два запроса.
Есть ли вариант ещё в исходном считать это сразу?
То есть, к примеру пользователь ввёл <=5.0
На выходе запроса получить:

```
pin_name 1 | среднее | количество сущностей с  pin_name 1 <=5.0 | true или false
pin_name 2 | среднее | количество сущностей с  pin_name 2 <=5.0 | true или false
```

Где `true - среднее <=5.0, false - обратное`.

Comment: `sum(case when  value < 5 then 1 else 0 end)` - количество записей с `value` меньше 5, если вы про это.

Comment: или просто `sum((value < 5)`, и аналогично `(avg(meas) < 5) as truefalse`

Comment: @teran, именно это! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В более общем случае, для различных СУБД подобное пишут с использованием оператора `case` и агрегатной функции суммирования:

```
 select sum(case when meas < 5 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Для диалекта mysql можно более кратко записать как

```
select sum(IF(meas < 5, 1, 0))
```

И поскольку у нас тут либо 0 либо 1, то и вовсе сократить до

```
select sum( meas < 5)
```

Схожим образом можно оформить и решение для последнего вашего столбца

```
select ( avg(meas) < 5 ) as truefalse
```

Так что ваш запрос дополнится такими строками

```
SELECT
    measuring.pin_name AS pin_name,
    AVG(measuring.meas) AS meas,
    COUNT(measuring.meas) AS counts,
    SUM(measuring.meas < 5) as c_lt5,
    (AVG(measuring.meas) < 5) as truefalse
```

Comment: Спасибо! Если не покажусь слегка наглым - есть ли способ посчитать медиану  по pin_name x?

Comment: [способы то есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263925/1216425), но не такие простые :)

Comment: уф, эти видел, но пока побоялся разбираться) На текущий момент просто отдельным столбцом добавляю все значения по pin_name через запятую, а на выходе обрабатываю средствами Python.